# Grease pencil line art is missing edges

Tags: grease-pencil, lineart

I want to outline the edges of the following *chip* object using a grease pencil line art modifier. However, it only outlines some of the edges: only the ones forming the silhouette of the object. The other edges are missed, even though their angles (90° and 135°) are well within the set threshold. I added a cube to show that similar edges are outlined there. Any idea what could be going wrong?

[image: missing lines]

Here's the .blend file, in case that helps.

[image]

Comment: For some reason, your chip object isn't affected by *Line Art* modifier > *Edge Types* > *Crease Threshold*. I'm unable to find why. Any idea what operation/modification you may have done on the chip object ?

Comment: @Lutzi I created it by importing the shape from a .dxf file, converting that to a mesh and then extruding. Maybe that has something to do with it? I would have thought that the final mesh should be identical to one created by other means..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Correct normals

Some of your normals are pointing inwards. First select your chip object, go to *Edit Mode*, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate outside*.

#### Disable auto-smooth

Still with the chip object selected, disable *Auto-smooth*

[image: Disabling auto-smooth]

#### Tweak grease pencil

Select your grease pencil object. Then you can tweak the *Crease Threshold*. If you go all the way to 180°, you'll see one of your face isn't flat. You could just set it to 179°, or rework your geometry to have flat faces.

[image: Tweaking crease threshold]